# Agrupar por categoría en accordion (HTML - PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, accordion

Tengo una pagina de ventas en la q vendo distintos productos, en una plantilla de la pagina de admin tengo un `accordion` el cual quiero agrupar por categoría de las ventas que se van realizando, por ejemplo, se vendieron 10 objetos con la categoría "1" y 3 objetos con la categoría "2", necesito que en un `card`, dentro del `accordion`, aparezcan los datos de los 10 objetos con la categoría "1" y en otro `card` los 3 objetos con la categoría "2", lo que tengo echo hasta ahora me muestra todos los datos pero cada uno en un `card` distinto, tengo 10 objetos con la categoría "1" y me muestra 10 `card` distintos. Alguna ayuda? Adjunto todo mi código debajo:

```
session_start();
include '../php/conexion.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['datos_login'])) {
  header("Location: ../index.php");
}

$arregloUsuario = $_SESSION['datos_login'];
if ($arregloUsuario['nivel']!= 'admin') {
  header("Location: ../index.php");
}

$resultado = $conexion->query("
  select ventas.*, usuario.nombre, usuario.telefono, usuario.email 
  from ventas inner join usuario on ventas.id_usuario = usuario.id ORDER BY ventas.fecha DESC")or die($conexion->error);
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

$resultado_categoria= $conexion->query("
  select productos_venta.categoria, ventas.id
  from productos_venta inner join ventas on productos_venta.id_venta = ventas.id 
  ")or die($conexion->error);
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Pedidos</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- summernote -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dashboard/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.css">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
<div class="wrapper">


  <?php include "./layouts/header.php";?>
  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0">Pedidos</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">

       <div id="accordion">
        <?php    
          while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_categoria)) {
        ?>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  <?php echo $f['categoria'];?>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-small btnEliminar" style="float: right;"
                  data-id="<?php echo $f['categoria'];?>"
                  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p >Nombre cliente: <?php echo $datos['nombre']; ?></p>
                <p >Email cliente: <?php echo $datos['email']; ?></p>
                <p >Telefono cliente: <?php echo $datos['telefono']; ?></p>
                <p >Status de la venta: <?php echo $datos['status']; ?></p>
                <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>   
                      <th>Precio</th>
                      <th>Talla</th>
                      <th>Color</th>
                      <th>Cantidad</th>
                      <th>Subtotal</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>       
                      <?php 
                      $re=$conexion->query("select productos_venta.*, productos.nombre, productos.talla, productos.color
                        from productos_venta inner join productos on productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id where productos_venta.id_venta =".$f['id'])or die($conexion->error);
                        while ($f2 = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
                      ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $f2['id'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $f2['nombre'];?></td>
                          <td>$<?php echo number_format($f2['precio'],2,'.','');?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $f2['talla'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $f2['color'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $f2['cantidad'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $f2['subtotal'];?></td>
                        </tr>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- Modal eliminar -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEliminar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalEliminarLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalEliminarLabel">Eliminar producto</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ¿Desea eliminar el producto?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger eliminar" data-dismiss="modal">Eliminar</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php include "./layouts/footer.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, sería tratar de simplificar:

- **Lógica**: Obtener los resultados ordenados por categoría y, después fecha, de forma que puedas agruparlos fácilmente en la salida
- **Recursos**: Estás realizando 3 consultas:

```
$resultado = $conexion->query("
  select ventas.*, usuario.nombre, usuario.telefono, usuario.email 
  from ventas inner join usuario on ventas.id_usuario = usuario.id ORDER BY ventas.fecha DESC")or die($conexion->error);

$resultado_categoria= $conexion->query("
  select productos_venta.categoria, ventas.id
  from productos_venta inner join ventas on productos_venta.id_venta = ventas.id 
  ")or die($conexion->error);

$re=$conexion->query("select productos_venta.*, productos.nombre, productos.talla, productos.color
    from productos_venta inner join productos on productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id where productos_venta.id_venta =".$f['id'])or die($conexion->error);
```

Las 3 pueden simplificarse en una sola, donde obtengas todos los datos necesarios en el orden adecuado:

```
$res = $conexion->query('SELECT productos_venta.*, ventas.*,
        productos.nombre, productos.talla, productos.color,
        usuario.nombre, usuario.telefono, usuario.email
    FROM productos_venta
    INNER JOIN ventas ON productos_venta.id_venta = ventas.id
    INNER JOIN productos ON productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id
    INNER JOIN usuario on ventas.id_usuario = usuario.id
    ORDER BY productos_venta.categoria, ventas.fecha') or die ($conexion->error);
```

El único problema que veo en esto, es que en todas las tablas tienes una columna ID y se va a sobrescribir, a menos que uses un alias para cada tabla donde sea requerida, por ejemplo: `productos_venta.*, productos_venta.id as id_productos_venta`, Pero no es lo ideal, en todo caso, evita usar `productos_venta.*` y especifica una a una las columnas que quieras obtener de cada tabla.

Ahora, vamos con la lógica: Debes crear un contenedor para cada categoría y solo puedes hacerlo si llevas un control de cuál fue la última categoría mostrada, que se puede hacer con una simple variable, inicializada en `null`:

```
// Define la variable antes de iniciar el ciclo
$categoria = null;
// Te recomiendo usar fetch_assoc() en lugar de fetch_array()
// Porque solo accedes a columnas por nombre y no por posición
while ($f2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    // Analizas el valor de $categoría para saber si hay que crear contenedor
    if($f2['categoria'] !== $categoria) {
        // ¿Hay que cerrar contenedor anterior?
        // Solo si $categoria no es igual a null
        if($categoria !== null) {
            // Cerrar contenedor anterior
            // Esto es solo un ejemplo, considera todos los elementos creados
            echo '</tbody></table></div>';
        }
        // Crear nuevo contenedor (div, encabezados, más divs, tabla, etc.)
        echo '<div class="card"><table><thead></thead><tbody>';
        // Actualizar variable para no crear contenedor hasta nueva categoría
        $categoria = $f2['categoria'];
    }
    // Aquí creas el contenido de cada producto
    echo '<tr><td>Contenido</td></tr>';
}
// Al final, si hubo resultados, habrá un contenedor abierto
if($categoria !== null) {
    // Cerrar contenedor anterior
    echo '</tbody></table></div>';
}
```

**Importante:** Si bien, con esta propuesta podrías obtener el resultado esperado, lo ideal sería separar lógica de salida HTML, seguramente, usando algún sistema de plantillas, pero eso ya es otro tema.

Solo te queda solucionar el "problema" de las columnas `id` y, tal vez, filtrar la consulta por rango de fecha.

**Edición:** A simple vista, toma estos elementos, ajusta las variables, de acuerdo a como se recorre el ciclo `while ($f2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))` todas deben ser `$f2['nombre_de_columna']` y coloca las piezas de código en el bloque que les corresponde:

### Contenedor de categoría

```
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              <?php echo $f['categoria'];?>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-small btnEliminar" style="float: right;"
              data-id="<?php echo $f['categoria'];?>"
              data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminar">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $f['categoria']; ?>" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p >Nombre cliente: <?php echo $datos['nombre']; ?></p>
            <p >Email cliente: <?php echo $datos['email']; ?></p>
            <p >Telefono cliente: <?php echo $datos['telefono']; ?></p>
            <p >Status de la venta: <?php echo $datos['status']; ?></p>
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>   
                  <th>Precio</th>
                  <th>Talla</th>
                  <th>Color</th>
                  <th>Cantidad</th>
                  <th>Subtotal</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
```

### Fila de cada producto

```
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $f2['id'];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $f2['nombre'];?></td>
                      <td>$<?php echo number_format($f2['precio'],2,'.','');?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $f2['talla'];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $f2['color'];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $f2['cantidad'];?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $f2['subtotal'];?></td>
                    </tr>
```

### Cerrar contenedores de categoría

```
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Vaya... que respuesta mas completa, aun así hace horas estoy dándole vueltas al asunto, soy estudiante y prácticamente soy nuevo en todo esto, no logro comprender del todo bien la forma correcta de aplicar este código.

Comment: @FranSchiavone, ¿qué parte es la que no entiendes?

Comment: La parte de la consulta sql ya esta resuelta... no logro comprender del todo bien la forma de como crear un contenedor para cada categoría, no logro unir tu código con el mío que tenia realizado anteriormente. @Triby

Comment: @FranSchiavone, acabo de editar la respuesta para mencionar lo que corresponde a cada bloque.

Comment: muchas gracias, la verdad que muy bien explicado todo, no te falto ni un detalle. De 10!